# Ubuntu 16.04 running hotter than Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, windows-7, temperature

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu as my new primary OS, and I really, really want to like it. There have been and still are quite a few issues I've had to resolve, but most have been easy enough to fix.

However, one issue that may be a deal breaker is that Ubuntu is running about 10*F hotter than Windows 7.

I've disabled my Nvidia card, updated my Intel Graphics drivers, and installed TLP, but the temps still remain about 10*F above Windows 7, with Windows idling at 108*F and Ubuntu at 118*F.

There are many possible reasons for this I'm sure, so how would I go about finding what's raising my temps? The System Monitor & "top" don't seem to show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Idling at 118F is ok. If you like, uninstall TLP and install thermald for temp control... but don't expect idle temp to change (much or at all).

Comment: @heynnema True, 118*F isn't that bad, but it's just the fact that it's hotter than Windows...

Comment: While trying to figure this out, I went and removed some of the packages I had installed. I have a suspicion that FingerprintGUI might have been the cause, because the idle temps are currently at 108*F and below. Will keep an eye on it and mark as answered if that seems to have fixed it.